# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{" not sure why

Tags: reactjs, frontend

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

class Rando extends Component {
    state = {
        num: 0,
        makeTimer()
    };
    makeTimer() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.maxNum);
            this.setState({num: rand});
        }, 1000);
    }
    render() {
        return <h1>{this.state.num}</h1>;
    }
}

export default Rando;
```

why is this occuring. im really confused what is going on. can someone help clarify this for me?

Comment: Can you post the full log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the name of the makeTimer property inside state, also you need to use this to reference the function

```
    state = {
        num: 0,
        someName: this.makeTimer()
    };
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept it as the answer.